# Integrating code with payeezy.js file

Tags: encryption, tokenize, pci-compliance

I have downloaded code from github/payeezy and wrote php page to integrate with payeezy.js file

```html
<script src="https://developer.payeezy.com/v1/payeezy.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

also set required parameters

```
Payeezy.setApiKey('...');
Payeezy.setMerchantIdentifier('..');
```

What is next step to integrate with payeezy.js to call authorize capture ?

Comment: SO isn't a code writing service. Show some effort in integrating with payeezy.js to call authorize capture and someone may be able to help when it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

The next step is Setting up Payment Information Page:
Payeezy.js has to be initialized for setting up the Payment information page, all Personally Identifiable Information (PII) fields on the form should have an attribute “payeezy-data”. It is important that these fields do not have the “name” attribute. By not having the “name” attribute, the browser doesn’t not send that information back to the merchant server.  All the fields that are not PII will be submitted to the Merchant server. You can start with the following sample code.

```
<form action="{call to merchant server}" method="post" id="payment-info-form" >
<span class="payment-errors"></span>
<div class="row">
<label>Card Type : </label>
<select payeezy-data="card_type">
<option value="visa">Visa</option>
<option value="mastercard">Master Card</option>
<option value="American Express" >American Express</option>
<option value="discover" >Discover</option>
</select>
</div>
<div class="row">
<label>Cardholder Name : </label>
<input type="text" payeezy-data="cardholder_name"value="Tom Eck"/>
</div>
<div class="row">
<label>Card Number : </label>
<input type="text" payeezy-data="cc_number"value="4788250000028291"/>
<div>
<div class="row">
<label>CVV Code : </label>
<input type="text" payeezy-data="cvv_code"value="123"/>
</div>
<div class="row">
<label>Expiry Date : </label>
<select payeezy-data="exp_month">
<option value="01">01</option>
<option value="02">02</option>
<option value="03">03</option>
<option value="04">04</option>
<option value="05">05</option>
<option value="06">06</option>
<option value="07">07</option>
<option value="08">08</option>
<option value="09">09</option>
<option value="10">10</option>
<option value="11">11</option>
<option value="12" selected>12</option>
</select>
<select payeezy-data="exp_year">
<option value="14" selected>2014</option>
<option value="15">2015</option>
<option value="16">2016</option>
<option value="17">2017</option>
<option value="18">2018</option>
</select>
</div>
<div class="row">
<label>Merchant Ref : </label>
<input type="text" name="merchant_ref" id="merchant_ref" value="Token Testing"/>
</div>
<div class="row">
<label>Transaction Type : </label>
<select id="transaction_type" name="transaction_type" >
<option value="purchase" >Purchase</option>
<option value="authorize" selected="selected" >Authorize</option>
</select>
</div>
<div class="row">
<label>Amount : </label>
<input type="text" name="amount" id="amount" value="101"/>
</div>
<button type="submit">Make Payment</button>

</form>
```

Comment: We are not PCI compliance. Does this JS file support Transparent redirect functionality? Do you have any documentation ?